# Multiple SSH keys - not identifying

Tags: ssh

I have a set of SSH keys working correctly, but I now need multiple keys for connection to other servers.

I have set up a new set of keys for the new server, adding an identifier to the files of 'lightand'. The keys are:

```
id_rsa_lightand
id_rsa_lightand.pub
```

I have added the public key into the 'authorized_keys' file and placed the private key on my local machine (in .ssh folder).

On the local machine, I have then set up a 'config' file and added the following:

```
Host lightand@servers.prgn.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lightand
```

I have then run:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lightand
```

However, with the above completed, I still get a password prompt through terminal.

Does anyone have any ideas on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Your `Host` line should have just the hostname and you should add a line underneath with `User lighthand`.  If that doesn't work, show us the output from `ssh -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the ssh config file contained an error preventing it from loading the appropriate key.

```
Host lightand@servers.prgn.com
```

Since the hostname is only servers.prgn.com, that host line will never match when you ssh to servers.prgn.com.  The configuration file requires that usernames be on a separate line.  Changing the configuration to the following should fix your issue:

```
Host servers.prgn.com
    User lightand
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_lightand
```

If you ever need to see what your ssh client is doing behind the scenes as it is running, just use `ssh -v`.